# Making list of lists from ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'] to [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]

Tags: python

How to make list of lists from:

```
data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

to

```
data = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
```

Comment: I am sorry that I am newbie in python. I fail to assign value of data by using data = [data[i, i+3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)] in order to achieve the result of [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]

Comment: you've made a typo: `[data[i: i+3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]`

Comment: you should just copy paste the code to see if it works first

Answer (score 1):

```
[a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
```